# Вызов функции только один раз jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция jQuery, при вводе текста цели передаются в метрику и аналитикс:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
        yaCounterXXXXX.reachGoal('namepage');
        ga('send', 'pageview', 'namepage');
    });
```

Проблема в том, что keyup работает на каждый введенный символ. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы вызов был лишь единожды? Сработает ли такой вариант:

```
var count_keyup = 0;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    count_keyup++;
    if (count_keyup == 0) {
    yaCounterXXXXX.reachGoal('namepage');
    ga('send', 'pageview', 'namepage');
        }            
});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может лучше инпут на какой-то submit посадить?

Comment: @NeedHate ого, это как? Я даже и не знал о таком..)

Comment: Решение сильно зависит от реализации. Покажите код, это форма или где? Бьём из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Можно завязать на событие blur

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вместо keyup использовать change

Если не нужна вставка через контекстное меню

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textInp").bind({
        copy : function(){
        $('#msg').text('Вы скопировали текст!');
    },
    paste : function(){
        $('#msg').text('Вы вставили текст!');
    },
    cut : function(){
        $('#msg').text('Вы вырезали текст!');
    }
});
```

});

Вот ссылка откуда взят пример :
http://yournet.kz/blog/js/opredelyaem-kopirovanie-vyrezku-vstavku-teksta-v-jquery

Comment: А если не нужна отработка при вставки содержимого через контекстное меню?

Comment: Вобщем-то вставка с change ок работает, после вставки он тоже вызовется

Answer (score 0):

Для одноразового вызова события можно использовать метод one

```
$('input').one("keyup", function(e){
    yaCounterXXXXX.reachGoal('namepage');
    ga('send', 'pageview', 'namepage');
});
```